# Httpclient getResponseBodyAsString() returns not readable data

Tags: javascript

I am using httpclient in javascript to get file from a url and get response body as string to store in database.
My code works fine in case of text but, for other files extensions like excel or png it returns unreadable like below.

The response is:

```
PK!ëx%E[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´IOÃ0ïHüÈW¸p@5åÀrJqvIj/ò¸Û¿gÜ%j«¶)P.ç½÷ytfºN&àQY³ë¬Ã0ÒÊT9û¼¤w,Á L!jk gs@öÐ»¼èæ0!µÁBp÷£YVJëµtë+îüðNçKkèÁzÝ'(Å¸Éó/I©Xò¸|/FåLé¨Ïù^w$Â¹ZIho|b®tÅrñÃ+?W¶6Vº7*¦W$}áÃ«ÐDÎ§Ö¼°r¬i×Ùq=¶,FÝ·ét5+Z(³æ?ÈaÆzçi¬[!0ÌkÀó,}OÿTaô\ ém?i¬|¶ØÐ¶§ATïSB¶;'m;y\9·"Laøþoæ­ %µô@k8¡â?,FcÝ (small part of full log)
```

For image file:

```
.ß0ÊÍÍQ#0¶0¡ø")%P4ÓêÂ,J«üÙö  SògÖ59¥³÷eÞ3?»þ{0£E(Ú¢EäBûëTtÊ½6IEND®B` (small part of full log)
```

For text  the response is:

```
This is a test file.
```

My code is below :-

```
 var httpclient = Packages.org.apache.commons.httpclient;
  var HttpClient = httpclient.HttpClient;
  var GetMethod = httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var get = new GetMethod(url);
  var status = client.executeMethod(get);
  gs.log("Getting URL: " + url);

  gs.log("--------------Request Headers------------------");
  var reqHeaders = get.getRequestHEaders();
  for ( var i = 0; i < reqHeaders.length; i++) {
    gs.log(reqHeaders[i].getName() + " (REQ):" + reqHeaders[i].getValue());
  }

  gs.log("--------------Response Headers------------------");
  var headers = get.getResponseHeaders();
  for ( i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    gs.log(headers[i].getName() + " (RESP) :" + headers[i].getValue());
  }
    var is = get.getResponseBodyAsString();
 gs.log("The response is"+is);
```

Note : getResponseBodyAsStream(); is not an option.